# Build the proper array with push method to send data to google sheet in the right format

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

For a very specific goal, for which I won't go into detail here, I need to grab some data from one spreadsheet and send these data to another one. However I must use the push method somewhere in my code.

Concretely here is what I'm trying to do :

```
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw_data");
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet10");
  var Row_count = sheet.getLastRow()
  var raw_data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

   var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < Row_count ; i++) {
    data.push(raw_data[i].toString())
    }

sheet2.getRange(1, 1,1, 307).setValues([data]);
  }
```

So basically I would like to be able to breakdown the `getValues();` output and recompose it with the `push` method.

Right now all my data are being send in sheet2 on the same row. Using the push method how do I go to get the following output :

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,etc...
Data11,data12,data13,data14
Data21,data22,data23,data24
Data31,data32,data33,data34,
etc...
```

thanks !

Comment: Answerers should beware that Google Apps Script *isn't* JavaScript, it's its own language that's effectively JavaScript circa 2003/2004. So it doesn't have even the things added in the ECMAScript 5th edition spec.

Comment: You're right. I took off the Javascript tag. thanks.

Comment: I've found Google Apps Script to be a mixed bag. There are some undocumented methods available on certain objects. For example, Arrays have the map(), reduce(), some() and every() methods introduced in ECMAScript 5th edition of Javascript, so there is some degree of compliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)), the range you're pushing that data into should be the same shape as the data you're pushing, but it isn't if I'm reading [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) correctly. There are two differences: Your range is only one row high, and your range is 307 columns wide. But your data is `Row_count` rows high, and one column wide (with that column containing the result of converting the cells into a single comma-delimited string).

So I'd think changing your `getRange` at the end would be sufficient:

```
sheet2.getRange(1, 1, Row_count, 1).setValues([data]);
// -------------------^^^^^^^^---^
```

---

In a comment, you've said you want the data you pass to `setValues` to be the same shape as `raw_data`. Right now it isn't, `raw_data` is a two-dimensional structure; you're building a one-dimensional array with string-joined values and then wrapping it in another array — so it ends up being two-dimensional, but it's one row with `Row_count` columns.

You'll need nested loops if you want to build the same structure:

```
var data = [];
var row;
var dataRow;
var rowIndex;
var Col_count = raw_data[0].length;
var colIndex;
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < Row_count; rowIndex++) {
    row = raw_data[i];
    dataRow = [];
    data.push(dataRow);
    for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
        dataRow.push(row[colIndex]);
    }
}
sheet2.getRange(1, 1, Row_count, Col_count).setValues(raw_data);
```

Comment: Thanks. No it doesn't. I'm just adapting it because if not I have an error. Actually I would like to get able to have the following `getRange(1,1,307,17)`

Comment: @SimonBreton: I'm not quite following you. Why 307 rows and 17 columns? The data you're setting is only one column wide.

Comment: @SimonBreton: Separately, not quite sure what the "it" you're referring to in "No it doesn't" is?

Comment: No It's not. For example If I'm passing the of `raw_data` directly, the `getRange` is like this `sheet2.getRange(1, 1,307, 17).setValues(raw_data);` is this clearer ?

Comment: @SimonBreton: `raw_data` may well be 307x17, but that's not what you're building in your loop. Is it what you *want* to build in your loop?

Comment: Yes exactly ! that's it !